# c# SQL Query error when trying to join a table

Tags: c#, sql

I am having diffculties joining a table in my code. Below you can see my code, I am getting an error on the join 2 table trying to connect my parts table.

```
if (query.Any()) // Check if REG is in the Database
{
    int carID = query.FirstOrDefault().Id;
    string carRegg = query.FirstOrDefault().regNo;
    string carMake = query.FirstOrDefault().Make;
    string carModel = query.FirstOrDefault().Model;


    var test = (from a in dbC.Cars
                where a.Id == carID
                join b in dbC.Services on a.Id equals b.ServiceWrkNo
                join c in dbC.PartsUseds on b.ServiceWrkNo equals c.PartsUsedNo
                join d in dbC.Parts on c.PartsUsedNo equals d.PartName
                select new
                {
                    serviceNum = b.ServiceWrkNo,
                    PartNo = c.PartsUsedNo,
                    replacedParts = d.PartName
                }).ToList();
```

the database I created from a model first method is below.

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is not an sql query. It's a linq query.

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining the Id column in Cars to the CarId column in Service, instead of the ServiceWrkNo?  In fact all your joins seem to be on the wrong columns of each table instead of the correct foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join do seems a little bit off -- could you try the join with the following columns

```
var test = (from a in dbC.Cars
            where a.Id == carID
            join b in dbC.Services on a.Id equals b.CarId
            join c in dbC.PartsUseds on b.ServiceWrkNo equals c.ServiceServiceWrkNo
            join d in dbC.Parts on c.PartsPartNo equals d.PartNo
            select new
            {
                serviceNum = b.ServiceWrkNo,
                PartNo = c.PartsUsedNo,
                replacedParts = d.PartName
            }).ToList();
```